# VCenter 6.5 installation - internal error

Tags: vmware, esxi, vcenter

I'm getting an error "internal error" when trying to "Set up vCenter Server Appliance" as shown in the attached screenshot:
[image: screenshot 1]

It starts as shown in the second screenshot and then it throws the internal error, it looks like it's failing to set the host name.

[image: screenshot 2]

I already checked /var/log/messages but there is nothing helpful there, is there any other log files that I  need to check that might show the exact error?

The vCenter is installed on eSXI 6.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the 'server name' option blank? It should automatically revert to the IP address instead of having to type it in. Another thought, configuring the DNS server to a valid IP address might be worth a shot. (doesn't matter if it will respond DNS requests properly or not, just a valid IP address)

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and I'll let you know how it goes, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Having run into exactly this issue in my case it transpired that the DNS server that is set in the console of the appliance is the one used to look up the name. If the name won't look up in *that* dns server you get this error. The DNS server that you set in the VCS appliance configuration screen (the one on https://vcs-appliance:5480) appears not to be used). You need to open the console in ESXi view of the virtual machine and set the DNS server there.

Of course if you specify an IP address for the host name this doesn't happen because it doesn't look the host name up in DNS.

Not to say that that is the only reason you may see the error but it's enough in itself.

Comment: I can confirm your observations. I guess it happens, because the installer tries to set the host name, _before_ it tries to update the network settings. Furthermore I can only add, that the installer did not work with my router's (a Fritz!Box, being very popular in Germany) builtin DNS server, although `dig` (was able to do forward+reverse lookups) - thus I had to install my own (I went with CoreDNS) **and** I had to change the DNS server in the console to use the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable DNS resolve. open port TCP /UDP 53 from the VCSA ip to your DNS servers

Answer (score 0):

On ESX Server console config DNS was "auto".
i went back to vcenter console [F2] and configured my DNS server IP there (changed auto)  and went back do the "Set up vCenter Server Appliance"  .  Now the setup pulled my config and went ahead to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the "solution" at least it workds for me !
When you want to use IP address for the name just put "localhost" in the name field not the IP address that is already in the IP address field ! This way the installer will not fail with "internal error" during DNS checks.
I figured this out since "localhost" was present when i first entered the GUI config on port 4080 after having filled all information when deploying from the OVA.
Hope it will work for you this is my 2 cents :)